# Google's IAB API3 getSkuDetails() method returns failed 5: Developer Error

Tags: android, eclipse, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to incorporate Google's in-app-billing API3 in my code that has been using API2.

My call to mHelper (the IabHelper object) succeeds, so I am connecting to Google's servers. It appears that I can determine owned items, as my QueryInventoryFinishedListener returns a valid Inventory with all my purchased items. I am also able to execute a purchase.

However, querying for sku details fails (getSkuDetails()).  Here is all IabHelper-related LogCat output from Eclipse (I removed my package name and product SKUs) leading up to the failure:

```
12-31 11:47:04.642: D/IabHelper(13633): Starting in-app billing setup.
12-31 11:47:04.832: D/IabHelper(13633): Billing service connected.
12-31 11:47:04.832: D/IabHelper(13633): Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
12-31 11:47:04.832: D/IabHelper(13633): In-app billing version 3 supported for com.XXXX.XXXX
12-31 11:47:04.832: D/IabHelper(13633): Subscriptions AVAILABLE.
12-31 11:47:04.842: D/IabHelper(13633): Starting async operation: refresh inventory
12-31 11:47:04.842: D/IabHelper(13633): Querying owned items, item type: inapp
12-31 11:47:04.842: D/IabHelper(13633): Package name: com.XXXX.XXXX
12-31 11:47:04.842: D/IabHelper(13633): Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
12-31 11:47:04.912: D/IabHelper(13633): Owned items response: 0
12-31 11:47:04.912: D/IabHelper(13633): Sku is owned: com.XXXX.XXXX.item_one
12-31 11:47:04.922: D/IabHelper(13633): Sku is owned: com.XXXX.XXXX.item_two
...
(and 45 other items)
...
12-31 11:47:05.012: D/IabHelper(13633): Continuation token: null
12-31 11:47:05.012: D/IabHelper(13633): Querying SKU details.
12-31 11:47:05.012: D/IabHelper(13633): getSkuDetails() failed: 5:Developer Error
12-31 11:47:05.012: D/IabHelper(13633): Ending async operation: refresh inventory
```

It doesn't seem like a signing issue, since I can successfully connect and make a purchase.

Has anybody else been having issues where getSkuDetails() fails with the "Developer Error" message, while other aspects of in-app-billing work?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 22):

I've experienced the same problem. The issue appears to occur when you've more than 20 SKUs in your inventory.

The solution was to get the SKU details in chunks. Replace `querySkuDetails` in `IabHelper.java` with:

```
int querySkuDetails(String itemType, Inventory inv, List<String> moreSkus)
    throws RemoteException, JSONException {
    logDebug("Querying SKU details.");
    ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
    skuList.addAll(inv.getAllOwnedSkus(itemType));
    if (moreSkus != null) {
        for (String sku : moreSkus) {
            if (!skuList.contains(sku)) {
                skuList.add(sku);
            }
        }
    }

    if (skuList.size() == 0) {
        logDebug("queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.");
        return BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK;
    }

    while (skuList.size() > 0) {
        ArrayList<String> skuSubList = new ArrayList<String>(
                skuList.subList(0, Math.min(19, skuList.size())));
        skuList.removeAll(skuSubList);

        Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
        querySkus.putStringArrayList(GET_SKU_DETAILS_ITEM_LIST, skuSubList);
        Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,
                mContext.getPackageName(), itemType, querySkus);

        if (!skuDetails.containsKey(RESPONSE_GET_SKU_DETAILS_LIST)) {
            int response = getResponseCodeFromBundle(skuDetails);
            if (response != BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
                logDebug("getSkuDetails() failed: "
                        + getResponseDesc(response));
                return response;
            } else {
                logError("getSkuDetails() returned a bundle with neither an error nor a detail list.");
                return IABHELPER_BAD_RESPONSE;
            }
        }

        ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails
                .getStringArrayList(RESPONSE_GET_SKU_DETAILS_LIST);

        for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
            SkuDetails d = new SkuDetails(itemType, thisResponse);
            logDebug("Got sku details: " + d);
            inv.addSkuDetails(d);
        }
    }
    return BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK;
}
```

This method gets the SKUs in chunks of 18. It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, fellow! I have looking for the same solution more than a day, change a lot of things such as package names, versions, signatures, published new app in beta!.. But after reading your post I have remembered that we changed quantity of querying items from 12 to 50! Thank you a lot :-)

Comment: You my friend, are life saver. What a nasty bug.

Comment: The issue is caused by this google bug: https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=137

Comment: @uaaquarius unfortunately that project and issue tracker is deprecated. I can't seem to find anywhere to report this issue now. I wouldn't hold our breadth about it being fixed; I guess the work around will have to be more of a permanent fix.

Comment: Note that the although the code at https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/ is marked deprecated, it does have a newer version of `querySkuDetails` that has a similar fix to the one coded above.

Answer (score 4):

The number of SKUs is not always the reason. This also started hapenning after Google changed the way things work on the Developer Play Store.

**Before**, we only had to upload signed APK without publishing it.

**Now**, there are sections Beta and Alpha where you have to upload signed APK and **publish it** in order to user in-app purchasing. Don't forget to add yourself to the tester list and properly set a list of beta users.

Comment: Hi, just to clarify, do you mean we need to publish the apk before we can actually test the in-app billing? I have my apk in draft right now. Thanks!

Comment: Why is that according to the android developer site(http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html): "You don't need to publish the application on Google Play to test it." Thanks for your help.

Comment: oh sorry. Update: "You can publish an app to the alpha or beta distribution channels. This makes the app available on the Google Play store, but only to the testers you put on a "whitelist"." This is based on Google Services documentation(http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static). Maybe the Android training documentation is not yet update.

Comment: I am experiencing the same error over the past week with some of my apps but not all. The apk is actually published to prod, and the in-apps have been created after pushing the app to prod, and still getting this error. On another app, using identical code (with different bundle id and base 64 public key), getSkuDetails works fine. I am assuming this is a problem with Google Play, but definitely looking for someone to suggest something that might help.

Comment: @mstenroos You gave too few details. Impossible to take a guess. I suggest you open a new question on your issue.

Comment: @sandalone, it turns out my problem was that in my list of skus contained one sku that was the empty string, which apparently causes this problem as well. So, it was indeed a problem with my code, and not Google.